# How can I print the last digit of INT_MIN integer using putchar only?

Tags: c

I am not allowed to use abs or any other libraries.
Here is what I've tried so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
    int n = INT_MIN;

    if (n == INT_MIN)
    {
        int a = -n;
        a = n % 10;
        putchar(a + '0');
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The output is always "(" and not the correct answer.

Comment: Your 2nd statement is incorrect: you're throwing away the value of "-n" you assigned to "a". Q: What about `int a = (-n) % 10;`

Comment: That still gives the wrong output. Thanks for correcting me on "-n", I didn't notice that.

Comment: @user3121023 I forgot to mention, I'm not allowed to use abs

Comment: `abs(INT_MIN)` is not representable as an `int` if it uses twos complement, which most implementations do. Are you allowed to use `long int`?

Comment: You could add 1 to `INT_MIN`, then negate this. The last digit of `INT_MIN` will be 1 more than the last digit of this.

Comment: Trace every step of your program. In a debugger, step through each executable statement and print any variable it changed. If you do not have a debugger you can use or do not know how, insert a `printf` after each statement to show the values of variables. Figure out what is happening in your program, then figure out what to do about it.

Comment: Just a comment to the comments -- a `long` is the same size as `int` on many systems, so casting to `long` is not the correct solution.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Indeed.  `long long` *might* work, but that's not guaranteed, either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply modulus to the negative number first to get a single negative digit. Negate that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
    int n = INT_MIN;

    int a = -( n % 10);
    putchar(a + '0');
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I first tried @Barmar 's answer but that also failed. Turns out that your answer was spot on.

Answer (score 1):

When `n == INT_MIN`, do not use `a = -n` as that is *undefined behavior* (UB) since `-n` overflows `int` math.

Using `a = n%10` will result in some value [-9 ... 0] since `n < 0`.  No need to negate `a` before using it to print the digit, just subtract.

```
    int n = INT_MIN;
    int a = n%10;
    putchar('0' - a);
```

---

To print the entire `int`, note that there are more negative values `[INT_MIN ... -1]` then positive ones `[1 ... INT_MAX]`<sup>*1</sup>.  Instead of negating negative numbers to positives (and have UB with `INT_MIN`), negate positive ones to the negative side.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...

int n = {some value from INT_MIN to INT_MAX};
int a = n < 0 ? n : -n;

char buf[21];
char *p = buf + sizeof buf - 1;
*p = '\0';

do {
  p--;
  *p = '0' - a%10;
  a /= 10;
} while (a);

if (n < 0) {
  *--p = '-';
}
puts(p);
```

This approach works even if instead of `int`, we used `long long` or `intmax_t`.  We just need to adjust the buffer length.  `char buf[21]` big enough for 64-bit integers.

---

<sup>*1</sup> With the common 2's complement integer encoding, there is always one more negative.  With the rare 1s' complement and sign-magnitude encoding, likely to be dropped in C2x, there are the same.  Of course with those there may be a +0 *and* -0, yet let us leave that for historic programming.